# Jersey REST Server: how to add monitor GUI

Tags: java, apache, rest, user-interface, jersey

Hej everyone,

**Current state of my Project:**
As part of a distributed framework I'm working on I use a REST. Its a simple implementation in Java using Jersey and runs on Tomcat. It consumes calls from lots of other web services and has no direct user-interaction (so far). However beeing a central part of the whole framework and a lot of the other developer have to see its internal status. So far I had a simple REST call returning the log file and some extra information from the service.

**My task:**
For demonstration reasons I need to make this interface a bit more graphic (maybe add some GUI functions later). Also I have to change it from pull based to push based.
This pretty much means I cant do it as just another rest call anymore.
//EDIT more details for the GUI:
Currently the GUI only needs to be able to show some status pictures but it needs to update itself. It has to run in a browser. Later on some interactive parts might be needed (pushing buttons)

**Question:**
Is there a simple and easy to integrate tool/framework that would allow me to create a simple GUI (allowing for server push)?
At the moment I,m looking at Vaadin but im not sure if thats not overkill. Also I dint get it to work alongside the other code so far.

Hope someone can help me on this. I'm an absolute noob with all that web-service stuff, so I need something as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to push information, then have other services register a callback-address and make a rest call to those. (Define an interface to be implemented by them!) That's how I satisfied the push requirement in a project and it was well accepted by the clients. It's quite foolproof.

I am not quite sure what you want about that GUI? Maybe deliver a HTML5-Page with websockets to push-update the data?

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific on what I mean with GUI.